# Grails error message based on label gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

How to customize error message for required field in gsp file, to not show bean field name but field label in gsp?

So when I have bean like this:

```
class Bean {
    int number
}
```

And field like this:

```
<field:wrapper bean="${bean}" field="fieldName">
  <field:label field="${field}" code="reconfirmationForm.${field}.label" required="true" />
  <g:select name="${field}" value="${fieldValue(bean: bean, field: field)}" from="[true, false]" valueMessagePrefix="default.booleanSelectLabel" noSelection="['': '']" />
  <field:errors bean="${bean}" field="${field}" />
</field:wrapper>
```

And in properties I have:

```
default.blank.message={0} is required
reconfirmationForm.fieldName.label=My super field
```

How to have message:

```
My super field is required
```

And not:

```
number is required
```

I want to do that for every field (not only for number)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define another property in your `message.properties`

```
bean.number.blank = My super field is required
```

The pattern is basically the `className.propertyName.blank`. See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/ref/Constraints/blank.html

This way, Grails will automatically first look the domain & field specific message.

I'm not sure if you can make it generic so you have to define custom properties for every field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as you mentioned I'm looking for something more generic.